# StringTokenizer and Split don't work

Tags: java, android

I need a hand with a project that I have and I'm totally stuck here.

I try with SringTokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(auxiliar2, "+");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    try{
        Textos seleccion = new Textos();
        seleccion.setBook(st.nextElement().toString());
        seleccion.setSection(st.nextElement().toString());
        seleccion.setMemorization(st.nextElement().toString());
        texto.add(seleccion);
    }finally{           
    }
}
```

In the StringTokenizer make me the first loop correct, but when it does the second it didn't find the next element of 
seleccion.setMemorization(st.nextElement().toString());
And then I read that split works better then I used it.

```
String[] tokens = auxiliar2.split("+");
for (int x = 0; x < tokens.length-1 ; x++ ){
    Textos seleccion = new Textos();
    seleccion.setBook(tokens[x].toString());
    seleccion.setSection(tokens[x+1].toString());
    seleccion.setMemorization(tokens[x+2].toString());
    texto.add(seleccion);
    x = x+2;
}
```

But in this way it didn't work either. Here I tried, but I don't know why gives me only the chars of the string.

Please can you help me? Thanks!!!!

Comment: what is the input?? you should put the input as well so that alternate solution can be given.

Comment: `don't work` == `are used improperly`. There is a fair chance these 2 methods work as documented, otherwise someone would have noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as an argument, and `+` has special meaning within regular expressions.

Escape the `+` with a backslash `\`, then escape the backslash itself for Java.

```
String[] tokens = auxiliar2.split("\\+");
```